# how to delete a selected text box that was created at run time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that has two buttons- Add and Remove. The add button adds text boxes in a specific grid in the gui at the run time programmatically and text box names will be assigned at runtime too. I want the delete button to delete the selected text box that was generated at the run time from the gui. I am not aware of a way to delete the text box unless I know the text box name and I am not sure which way to go regarding this. I would appreciate even a little guidance. I am very new to WPF and I am sure I should be missing some obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic demo to add and remove elements in/from `Grid` :

***XAML:***

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
    Title="MainWindow"   Height="300" Width="300"        
    xmlns:Interact="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"       
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"       
    >   
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Add New Box" Click="Button_Click" />
            <Button Content="Remove Selected Box" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid  x:Name="mygrid">

        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

***Events:***

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox=new TextBox();            
        mygrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        textBox.Name = "textBox" + mygrid.RowDefinitions.Count;
        textBox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, mygrid.RowDefinitions.Count);
        mygrid.Children.Add(textBox);
    }       

    private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
        if (focusedElement is TextBox)
        {
            mygrid.Children.Remove(focusedElement as UIElement);
        }
    }
```

***Output***

[image: Gird Childeren]

Above is very basic WPF approach you can take, However i very much recommend you to look into `MVVM` pattern to easy to logic separation and flexibility (like @dotNEt suggested in his answer).

Comment: PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" -This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IndikaPathirage your welcome. Feel free to accept the answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MVVM, (which you should be in WPF), you can do this:

1. In the ViewModel, expose a public `ObservableCollection<T>` that would contain the business objects (e.g. a `User`) that you need to show TextBoxes for.
2. In the UI, add an `ItemsControl` and bind it to your `ObservableCollection`.
3. Define a `DataTemplate` that translates the business objects into TextBoxes and binds TextBox properties to business objects members.
4. Implement `Add` and `Remove` `RelayCommands` in the ViewModel.
5. Bind your Add and Remove buttons with these commands.

This will save you from the hectic of walking the visual tree and finding appropriate textboxes etc.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach too!